# Why is it reporting "Can't get value" when I ask for the title, not the value?

Tags: applescript

This is the same code as the application from my last few questions but this version is rewritten to run under "Script Editor" for debugging help.

The error is generated by this code's last line. Checking with Accessibility Inspector, **ALL of the menu items have NIL values** that is why I specifically reference the title instead.

```
-- `menu_click`, by Jacob Rus, September 2006
--
-- Accepts a list of form: `{"Finder", "View", "Arrange By", "Date"}`
-- Execute the specified menu item.  In this case, assuming the Finder
-- is the active application, arranging the frontmost folder by date.

on menuClick(mList)
    local appName, topMenu, r

    -- Validate our input
    if mList's length < 3 then error "Menu list is not long enough"

    -- Set these variables for clarity and brevity later on
    set {appName, topMenu} to (items 1 through 2 of mList)
    set r to (items 3 through (mList's length) of mList)

    -- This overly-long line calls the menu_recurse function with
    -- two arguments: r, and a reference to the top-level menu
    tell application "System Events" to my menuClickRecurse(r, ((process appName)'s ¬
    (menu bar 1)'s (menu bar item topMenu)'s (menu topMenu)))
end menuClick

on menuClickRecurse(mList, parentObject)
    local f, r

    -- `f` = first item, `r` = rest of items
    set f to item 1 of mList
    if mList's length > 1 then set r to (items 2 through (mList's length) of mList)

    -- either actually click the menu item, or recurse again
    tell application "System Events"
        if mList's length is 1 then
            click parentObject's menu item f
        else
            my menuClickRecurse(r, (parentObject's (menu item f)'s (menu f)))
        end if
    end tell
end menuClickRecurse

local destination, libraryName, choices
set destination to "/Users/bryandunphy/music"
set libraryName to "Testing.xml"
tell application "iTunes" to activate
menuClick({"iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…"})
tell application "System Events" to set the value of the text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" of process "iTunes" to libraryName
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to tell its front window's group 1's pop up button 1 to click
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to set choices to the title of every menu item of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of its front window
    repeat with ndx from 1 to count of choices
    if the value of choices's item ndx is "" then
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to select (the menu item of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of its front window whose title is equal to item (ndx - 1) of choices)
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the '**choices**' variable contains a list of strings, not a list of menu items, so remove `the value of`.

You can use the index of the menu instead of the `whose` clause --> `whose title is equal to (....)`.

```
repeat with ndx from 1 to count of choices
    if choices's item ndx is "" then
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to select (menu item (ndx - 1) of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of its front window)
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```